# PyCharm Missing items from autocomplete

Tags: numpy, autocomplete, pycharm, python-3.5

Function `numpy.random.randn()` (and possibly many, many more) does not appear in my autocomplete list in PyCharm. After importing `numpy` and typing `numpy.random.ran`, my autocomplete list consists only of (`random` and `ranf`) The function can be run though. I checked with another editor and the function appears normally. Why does this happen? Is there a way to fix this? I experimented with autocomplete settings for a bit, but with no success.